# Pip and python are in different paths?

Tags: python, pip, chatterbot

```
C:\Users\tanis>pip
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using 
'"c:\program files\python38\python.exe"  "C:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts\pip.exe" ': 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

## How do I fix this?

I'm trying to install `chatterbot` using pip but it's not working. For `chatterbot`, I had to install python 3.8.0 and after installing it, it messed up the path for installing python libraries and now pip install isn't working.

Comment: did you tried to copy `python` or `pip` from one folder to another?

Comment: if you have many Pythons then maybe you should renames files to `python3.8.exe` `pip3.8.exe` - it is standard method in Linux.

Comment: error shows `program files\python38` with lower `p`, `f`, `p` and later `\Program Files\Python38` with upper `P`, `F`, `P`. Maybe this makes problem.

Comment: BTW: if `python.exe` works then you can use `python.exe -m pip install ...`. Other idea: on LInux command `pip` is normal python's script and you can edit it in editor or IDE.